# Venn Diagrams confusion.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was doing the following question.

```
    illustrate the following using a venn diagram 
    A – B =  ~(~A ∪ B)     where as usual A-B={x : x ∈ A & x ∉ B}
```

I got the following.

[image: i got the following]

But surely A-B should look like this?

[image]

I'm really unsure about the steps I have to take to get to each step.

Could someone explain please?

Thanks!

Comment: Why should $A-B$ not have elements from $A$ that are not in $B$?

Comment: Oops i think im getting confused between A-b and ~A and ~B

Comment: Fine, so, do you get that the second diagram is not right?

Comment: Yes, does that mean the first one is right?

Comment: Yes, sure it does. What you have first is right one for $A-B$ and the second diagram is the right one for $\lnot A \cap \lnot B$ which is also $(A \cup B)^c$ y DeMorgan's laws.

Comment: generally  before A-B,you should  show A intersection B  and   adter that,A-B would be  all A  except points which would be in intersection region

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like this :

[image]

Comment: yes exacly @pedja ,as i indicated in my comment  +1